# Php simulate session requests which have different time duration

Tags: php

I have the following problem - I need to simulate two different situations when a request is made to my site.
In the first situation the request should take less time, in the second situation it should take more time for processing.

The reason I need this is to test session expiration period.

However, I do not know how to make requests with different duration, so I need your help here

Comment: What do you really need to test ? Your session expiration session ?

Comment: `sleep` in your test methods?

Comment: I need to test if when the request takes time before and after the session expires and then is renewed, everything goes smoothly and correct session information is written.

Answer (score 1):

your requirements are not really clear, but i am going to give you an example from what i understood

first, store the last time the user made a request

```
<?php
  $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
?>
```

in subsequent request, check how long ago they made their previous request (10 minutes in this example)

```
<?php
  if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 * 60 < time()) {
     // session timed out
  } else {
     // session ok
  }
?>
```

hope this helps!